# javascript validation, special characters are not allowed except '-' and '_'

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

First, im not a pro in javascript so please bear with me.

I need to create a validation where user is not allowed to enter any special character except  '-' and '_' (exampe :  '.', '/'  and '@' is not allowed).

I have tried to google and i know i can achieve this easily using javascript's REGEX. However, im not allowed to use REGEX, so i need to code it without using REGEX.

I dont want to manually validate each special character, so please help me out.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) You have given some examples of "special characters", but you have not given a rigorous definition. Unicode has tens of thousands of characters. 2) "not allowed to use regex" sounds like an idiotic restriction. Is there some particular attribute of regex that makes it unsuitable here?

Comment: you're "not allowed" to use regex? (why not? it's the obvious / easiest solution) you're not trying to get us to do your homework are you?

Comment: @Jon rather "homework assignment" than "idiotic". Or it's that the boss has the "regex is always slow" mindset.

Comment: @Jon speaking of your point #1 - I have voted to close.

Comment: @JanDvorak: My first thought was that someone actually disallowed this outside a homework context. Not sure what's worse: that I found that plausible or that I was probably way off target.

Comment: @Jon it's certainly possible without regex, and it might even be faster, and it _might_ be more readable for a person that doesn't speak regex, but still... your point stands. Does "special" mean non-alphanumeric charcters where the input is known to be ASCII (it's not)?

Comment: Yes, it is a homework and i dont know how to do it, so why cant i ask it here? I can achieve this easily by using regex in the real project, so whats your problem?

Comment: @BlazeTama: Asking is fine, but we expect your own efforts to appear in the question (*especially* if it's homework). Most people would not find it worthwhile to feed you an answer because noone would gain from that (not even you in the long term). And my complaint that the question is not well specified still stands -- there's also stuff like "I need it manually" then "I don't want to manually validate". We can't read your mind.

Comment: @Jon sorry for my english, i will edit it. As for effort, i already said that i google it and all i found and learned is regex. So i code it, but the law said that i cant use regex. All i can do now is checking those special characters manually

Answer (score 3):

So in this assignment, you're:

1. Not allowed to use regular expressions, and
2. Not allowed to "manually" (whatever that means) validate each "special character" (whatever that means)

I assume restriction #2 means you can't compare each character to a specific list, for instance, in a `switch` statement.

The third alternative is to compare character *codes* against valid *ranges*. You get the character code of a character via `charCodeAt(n)` (where `n` is the index in the string), and you compare ranges using `>` and `<` (or `>=` and `<=`, or a combination). For instance, `(x >= 10 && x <= 20)` tests to see if `x` is in the range `10-20` (inclusive).

You can also compare characters (rather than character codes) against ranges, provided you're very careful to understand what's going on. So for instance, if `c` contains a one-character string `"j"`, then the expression `(c >= "a" && c <= "z")` will be true. But if `c` contained `"J"`, that expression would be false, because case matters.

With that starting point, assuming you've been given some sort of definition of what a "special" character is, you should be able to write the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited my question because its not really clear before.

Do you mean i need to use the ASCII?

Comment: @BlazeTama: Character codes in JavaScript are not ASCII (except the first 127 of them). But yes, character codes or (per my edit) you can compare actual strings if you're careful.

Comment: So i still need to validate it manually, one by one, by using charCodeAt()? I was trying to find another answer (if possible). I will accept your answer if no one can give me a better solution. Its too bad i can only upvote once. Thanks

Comment: @BlazeTama: If you can't use a regular expression, then yes, you have to check each character yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific set of characters that are not allowed, you can test for their existence using the JS function `str.indexOf(<invalid character>);`. It should return `-1` if the character can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Create a HTML [`INPUT`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) element with a unique `ID` and get a reference to it.

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

You will need to check when a key is pressed.

[`onkeypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keypress)

by adding an event listener to the `INPUT` element

[`addEventListender`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

and if it is a character that is not allowed, then prevent it from being displayed.

[`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

otherwise allow it.

So, your code will be something like this.

HTML

```
<input id="myInput" type="text"></input>
```

Javascript

```
// get a reference to my input element
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

// add an event to that element that fires on keypress
myInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    // get the character from that keypress, make it lower case to reduce the number of checks required.
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.charCode).toLowerCase();

    if(/* not one of these characters */) {
        // prevent the character from being displayed
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Try doing a little more investigation for yourself and post what you have tried along with the problem that you encountered and cannot solve. SO is not here to do the work for you, but to help when you have a problem with something that you have tried and failed to get working. Be sure to fully specify the expectations of your code and what it is not doing. When possible provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue that you are having.

Comment: I appreciate your step by step guide, but i dont ask that and i dont need them, which means i understood SO is not for doing my work, so i just ask a spesific question, not asking for a step by step tutorial. Im afraid we have a little miss comunication here. Thanks for your help, its too bad i only can upvote once, i will try your solution.